# Install parse failed manifest error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am getting an error when running a project I am working on about notifications. The event log lists the error as:

"Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl433950800.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #41): Invalid process name remote in package com.example.xxx.xxx: must have at least one '.' separator"

I have narrowed this down to a line in my manifest that contains the following code:

```
  <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process="remote">
    </receiver>
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: what is `package` set to in `<manifest>` element?

Comment: This:     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lorddavid.kidstimefinal">